# Magento Widget Form _afterToHtml not called

Tags: magento

I have a Block Widget Form which is rendering nothing only on one instance of Magento. When I run the same code on different instances or even in the QA environment of this one particular customer, everything works OK. However when I move into production nothing renders on the page and the _afterToHtml method is not being called.

As you can see in the code below, I've highlighted with log messages the methods which are getting called and the ones which aren't. The container wraps a Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form which can be found below. This is not calling _prepareForm() although the constructor gets called. See code below.

```
    <?php
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Export_Orders
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    /**
     * Block constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('my_module');

        $this->_blockGroup = 'my_module';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_module_export';
        $this->_mode = 'orders';
        $this->_headerText = $helper->__('Export Orders');

        $helper->log("This is called");

        parent::__construct();
        $this->removeButton('reset');
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', $helper->__('Run Export Job'));

        $helper->log("This is called");

    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is called");
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getFormHtml()
    {
        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is NOT called");
        return parent::_getFormHtml();
    }

    protected function _afterToHtml($html)
    {
        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is NOT called");
        return $html . '<div>Anything?</div>';
    }


    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is NOT called");
        return '<div>Trying this out...</div>';
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('my_module')->__('New Export');
    }
}
```

And this is the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form:

```
<?php
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Export_Orders_Form
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is called");
        parent::_construct();
        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is called");
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('my_module');

        Mage::helper('my_module')->log("This is NOT called");

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
            'method'    => 'post'
        ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('export_settings', array(
            'legend'    => Mage::helper('my_module')->__('Export Configuration')
        ));

        $dateFormat = Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT;

        $fieldset->addField('from_date', 'date', array(
            'name' => 'from_date',
            'label' => $helper->__('From Date'),
            'title' => $helper->__('From Date'),
            'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'input_format' => $dateFormat,
            'format' => $dateFormat,
            'class' => "validate-date"
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('to_date', 'date', array(
            'name' => 'to_date',
            'label' => $helper->__('To Date'),
            'title' => $helper->__('To Date'),
            'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'input_format' => $dateFormat,
            'format' => $dateFormat,
            'class' => "validate-date"
        ));

        $storeSwitcher = $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'store_id',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('my_module')->__('Store'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('my_module')->__('Store'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('secret_key', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'secret_key',
            'label' => $helper->__('Secret Key'),
            'title' => $helper->__('Secret Key'),
            'required' => true
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Anyone come across a similar issue? Note that there is nothing in the exception.log and that our custom log also has nothing odd other than the debug statements you see in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: go to System--> Configuration--> Advanced--> Disable Modules Output--> and enable the modules output.